# Can I run two different graphics card for two separate monitors

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, fps

When I try run dual monitors on one graphics card, there's a stutter and sort of screen tearing since one monitor is 144Hz and one is 60Hz. Can I add a second GPU for the 60Hz monitor only?

I'm running Windows 10. The two cards I am using are a RTX 2080 and a GTX 1060.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: And what cards? On OSes older than windows 10, I THINK you can only run cards with the same driver. Windows 10 would be fine with more than one.

Comment: Windows 10, RTX 2080 and GTX 1060

Comment: That's an interesting combination of cards! :)